# New window Highcharts not render in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, highcharts

I'm trying to print a Highcharts chart through JavaScript. One of the requirements is that the printing has to be done in a separate window which means I can't use the .print() function included with Highcharts. So what I ended up doing is cloning the container for the highcharts and then sending it to the new window. It works fine for Chrome, Firefox, IE9/10 but in IE 8 only the axises are rendered.

Chrome:

[image: Chrome Highcharts]

IE8:

[image: IE8 Highcharts]

I found a bug report for Highcharts with a similar issue: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1560

According to the report is the problem is with IE8 compatibility mode which I'm not using. This issue is not present in IE9/IE10, Chrome, or Firefox.

Below is the code I'm using to send the markup to the new window. '/print' simply includes a couple of essential CSS files. I'm not sure why the event handler is attached like that; I was just told that it was done that way for a reason without any clarifications.

```
var clone = $('#highcharts-demo').clone().get(0);

var params = [
  'width='+screen.width,
  'height='+screen.height
].join(',');

var printWindow = window.open('/print', 'Print', params);
printWindow[printWindow.addEventListener ? 'addEventListener' : 'attachEvent'](
  (printWindow.attachEvent ? 'on' : '') + 'load', function () {
  printWindow.document.body.innerHTML += clone.outerHTML;
  printWindow.document.close();
  printWindow.focus();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is with jQuery.clone(). I don't know why, unfortunately.. However here is working solution:

```
var clone = document.getElementById('highcharts-demo');
```

And later:

```
printWindow.document.body.innerHTML += clone.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is an SVG Printing bug in IE, which can be "fixed" by the following CSS:

`svg { position: absolute !important }`

Don't know how relevant that is to your specific problem, but this question came up when I was searching for a solution to my own problem and that CSS was the fix.